# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "foo_bar" of relation "bar" already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I wrote a migration to add a new column `foo_bar` to some table `bar`.  When it came time to merge my branch, I discovered a coworker wrote the same migration as me.  We decided to nix mine and just use theirs.

Now when I run tests I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "foo_bar" of relation "bar" already exists

I can't seem to move past this and cannot find any content online on how to quell this nonsense.

**What I've Done**

- deleted my migrations

**What I've Tried**

- dropping my db and creating a new one
- deleting node_modules

The only thing that seems to work for me is to comment out all the addColumn calls to columns that we both had overlap with.  There's no way I'm going to continue to tolerate this!

Is there a way to somehow clear the cache of migrations that have previously been run on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can revert back to initial state by undoing all migrations with `db:migrate:undo:all` command. You can also revert back to a specific migration by passing its name in --to option.

`npx sequelize db:migrate:undo:all` per http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html

Problem solved!